# GetGeneratedAssemblyContents implementation (ITypeProvider)

Tags: f#

I am trying to implement a TypeProvider. I could not find proper samples and explanation on how to do to implement "GeneratedAssemblyContents".

I have taken a look with FSharp Samples. The examples are quite complicated.

Is there any simple way to implement this? I am using mono as VM.